# Meteor js: get full validation message with validatedmethod simpleschema

Tags: javascript, validation, meteor, simple-schema

I am new to Meteor js and I am trying to create a form following the official guide http://guide.meteor.com/methods.html#method-form. It suggests to use [mdg:validated-method](https://github.com/meteor/validated-method) package and aldeed:simple-schema for validation which are based on mdg:validation-error to return validation error messages to the client. The guide suggests this code then to handle validation

```
Invoices.methods.insert.call(data, (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
        if (err.error === 'validation-error') {
            // Initialize error object
            const errors = {
                email: [],
                description: [],
                amount: []
            };

            // Go through validation errors returned from Method
            err.details.forEach((fieldError) => {
                // XXX i18n
                errors[fieldError.name].push(fieldError.type);
            });

            // Update ReactiveDict, errors will show up in the UI
            instance.errors.set(errors);
        }
    }
});
```

but the problem is that only fieldError.type, fieldError.name and **first** human readable message from simple-schema are available in err.error. I use translated messages and field labels in simple-schema to get nice understandable validation error messages. So getting just object property name with "required" is unacceptable, especially in the case when message includes min/max constraints for example. I could not find any way to get simple-schema's validation context to retrieve the full list of human readable errors.

So my question is can I get full error messages on the client and how?
Or maybe there are better ways to achieve what I am trying to do?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I also added an [issue](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema/issues/574) to aldeed:simple-schema github  project

Answer (score 0):

Hi! Recently I have encountered with the same problem.
So I just create [pull request](https://github.com/aldeed/node-simple-schema/pull/101) with some code enhancement to solve this issue. Now when you submit form and call `validated-method` from client side like following:

```js
yourMethodName.call(data, (err) => {
 if (err.error === 'validation-error') {
   console.dir(err, 'error ')
  }
});
```

You will see `error object` in the `console`:

```js
{
  "errorType": "ClientError",
  "name": "ClientError",
  "details": [
    {
      "name": "firstName",
      "type": "required",
      "message": "First name is required"
    },
    {
      "name": "lastName",
      "type": "required",
      "message": "Last name is required"
    },
    {
      "name": "phone",
      "type": "required",
      "message": "Phone is required"
    },
    {
      "name": "email",
      "type": "required",
      "message": "Email is required"
    }
  ],
  "error": "validation-error"
}
```

So I just [copy that](https://superuser.com/questions/777213/copy-json-from-console-log-in-developer-tool-to-clipboard) from my console output.
In my case, the method is as follows:

```js
export const yourMethodName = new ValidatedMethod({
  name: 'my.awesome.method',
  validate: new SimpleSchema({
    firstName: { type: String },
    lastName: { type: String },
    phone: { type: Number },
    email: { type: String, regEx: SimpleSchema.RegEx.Email }
  }).validator({ clean: true }),
  run(doc) {
    YourCollection.insert(doc);
  }
});
```

If my pull request will be accepted, you can easy use [node-simple-schema](https://github.com/aldeed/node-simple-schema) (it is the next version of [meteor-simple-schema](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema)).
If it won't you can use my [fork](https://github.com/unknown4unnamed/node-simple-schema).

Hope this helps!

**EDIT:** Now this feature available in official node-simple-schema [package](https://github.com/aldeed/node-simple-schema).